# Help with fullcalendar

Tags: 7, javascript

I've installed FullCalendar in Drupal 7, I have more than one event in the same day, so in the month view all this events shown in same cell and the cell height is increased badly and effects other theme regions, I read about the view more extension but I cant add it, I also try to edit the css to set max height and make overflow hidden but same.

Comment: post an image and css, so that we can find out what is wrong

Comment: first thank you for your reply and ,sorry for late reply.i tried to give max-height and overflow:hidden to the day cell in month view,but still growing when new event added in same day.i knew that the best solution is here  in this [link](https://github.com/timplunkett/fullcalendar.viewmore) but i do not know how to add it to my site.if u know, pls tell me